# HTTP incorrect response when that received by nc

Tags: http, curl, request, netcat

When i getting response of HTTP with nc command that have incorrect result.
for example

```
$nc site.it 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: site.it
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 07:34:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Debian)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

17b
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Index of /</title>
```

but when i using curl command result is

```
$curl -v site.it
* Rebuilt URL to: site.it/
*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to site.it (1.2.3.4) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: site.it
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 07:39:44 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Debian)
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Index of /</title>
```

In this case first request that uses `nc` command have a additional char **`17b`** that is not available to real source of page.
could someone tell me why it's occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the response is sent back using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, so that **17b** is the size (in hex) of the first chunk of data. curl, being a HTTP/1.1 compliant client, will decode that for you and only should the actual body contents.

See [RFC 7230 section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1) for details on the format.